# how to trim a Byte() in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I am trying to use socket to transfer byte to client. I define 
Byte(1024) because I am not sure how many character is the server sending!

I don't know how many index of this array has been occupied!?

Answer (score 0):

Your socket reading function should return a number indicating how much of the array it filled in.